# send function to child component hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

**edited: solved, missing curly brakets in arguments**

hope you can clarify this issue:
I have parent component:

```
function App() {
const [change, setChange] = useState(true);


const handleChange=(mode)=>{
  setChange(mode);
  console.log('change',change);
  
}

  return (
    <>
    
      <Navigation modes={handleChange}/>
```

and I am trying to send handlechange to the child component to change "change" state(sorry for the naming). I have the child component as it follows:

```
export default function Navigation({modes}) {
    const [mode, setMode] = useState(true);

const handleMode=(mode)=>{
        setMode(mode)
    }

useEffect(() => {
        modes(mode);
       }, [ mode ]);

return (
        
            
                <div className="nav__switch">
                    <Switch handleMode={handleMode}/>
                </div>
```

and the final component, the one that will update the mode:

```
export default function Switch({modes}) {
    const [mode, setMode] = useState(true);


    useEffect(() => {
        modes(mode)
      }, [mode]);

    const modeChange=()=>{

        mode?setMode(false):setMode(true);
        console.log(mode)
    }
```

there is a modeChange function that changes the state of mode that will be taken as an argument for the function on the parent element, however I am getting the error saying that "modes" is not a function, I console logged it and I can see that it is an object with default properties.

Does anybody knows what I am doing wrong here?

thanks

Comment: Are you referencing the right components? You have `<Navigation/>` and `<Switch/>`

Comment: this was one thing wrong, thank you very much, I already corrected it but still the same issue, do you have any idea?, the post has been edited with the new updates @Dor-Ron

Comment: solved, missing curly brakets in arguments, thanks"!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing it right but you are not waiting until it sets the state. you are console logging before the that makes the change happens. you need to wait until it does change. I think you should wait for a moment and see if it works. wrap your console.log with set interval function and see it if there is any difference

```
setTimeout(function(){ console.log(mode); }, 3000);
```

I this kind of cases you have to use js promises, async, awaits to make the execution wait until the task is done. [checkout the documentation about promises here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: awesome. grate job buddy.